# Joomla backend - redirect to different view after performing task

Tags: joomla, components, backend

In my joomla component's backend I have two views: `table` and `def` (which is just default view).

View `table` shows us table list of elements, I also have a toolbar created with `JToolbarHelper` which contains few buttons. These actions are handled by `MyComNameControllerTable` controller.

How can I redirect after performing this tasks back to `table` view?

So in my situation user is at `table` -> task is send to `def` controller -> I want to return to `table` view.

Right now I don't know why my controller after performing taskts redirects to `Def` view

Here is my controller:

```
class MyComponentControllerTable extends JControllerAdmin{
protected $text_prefix = '';

function __construct()
{
    $this->view_list = "table";
    parent::__construct();
}

function getModel($name="Table", $prefix='LandingPageModel', $config=array('ignore_request' => TRUE )){
    $model = parent::getModel($name, $prefix, $config);
    return $model;
}


function myTask(){

      // do something and redirect to Table view
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
function myTask(){

    // do something and redirect to Table view
    $this->setRedirect('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=table');
}
```

But be careful, I think "table" is a reserved word in Joomla and should not be used as a view name. Also list views should be named plural and forms singular.

- List view: cars
- Form/item view: car

It might be easier for you to build your first component using http://www.component-creator.com and then look at the code it writes for you.